# Installing C++ plugin in eclipse luna 4.4.1

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide

I've tried to install C++ plugin with "Install new software" in Eclipse Lina 4.4.1
I am running ubuntu 14.04

The error i get while installing is:

> An error occurred while installing the items
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> >>>[R]org.eclipse.cdt.autotools.core.source 1.4.0.201409172108, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.AddSourceBundleAction).
>   org/eclipse/equinox/internal/simpleconfigurator/utils/SimpleConfiguratorUtils
>   org/eclipse/equinox/internal/simpleconfigurator/utils/SimpleConfiguratorUtils

How can i solve this? I would really like to install this C++ plugin in my eclipse :(

Answer (score 0):

I would just go with [CDT](https://eclipse.org/cdt/). It doesn't look like that's what you're installing from the error you posted.

Comment: Yea, but that's where i am installing from ;P I went to your link and copied this url and added in install new software: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.5